# Javascript: registration form help required

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a rookie scripter and what I'm trying to do is: create a registration form and a calculator. If you enter a password less than 5 symbols or a username less than 3 symbols you will not be able to continue. But even if I enter an username with more than 3 symbols and a password with more than 5 symbols it still displays the error message.

The code: http://pastebin.com/KqYbDJMw

```
var user = document.forms[0].username.value;
var pw = document.forms[0].password.value;

function triggerCalc(){
    if (pw.length < 5 && user.length < 3){
        alert("An error occured");
    }
    else  {
        alert("Thank you for registering to my website.");
        var action = prompt("Welcome to my calculator. For addition press 1, for substraction press 2, for multiplication press 3, for division press 4 and for square root press 5:", "");

        var firstNum = new Array();
        var secondNum = new Array();
        var result = new Array();
```

Comment: Post your code here please.

Comment: I edited the relevant parts of your code into the question - in the future try to include such code in your question :)

Answer (score 3):

You want to fail if **either** of those conditions are true, so use `||` (or) instead of `&&` (and)

```
if (pw.length < 5 && user.length < 3)
```

should be

```
if (pw.length < 5 || user.length < 3)
```

Also, you want to fetch the **current** values *each time* you do your check, so this

```
var user = document.forms[0].username.value;
var pw = document.forms[0].password.value;
```

should be **inside** your function.  Ie

```
function triggerCalc(){
    var user = document.forms[0].username.value;
    var pw = document.forms[0].password.value;
```

Comment: I thought about that, but it doesn't work like that either. Still the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you get :

```
var user = document.forms[0].username.value;
var pw = document.forms[0].password.value;

function triggerCalc(){...
```

on load. So it will always be blank. To get it at the time the user clicks 'continue..' move it inside the function like so:

```
function triggerCalc(){
var user = document.forms[0].username.value;
var pw = document.forms[0].password.value;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not too far off.  The two main changes are you need to put your variable assignment inside of the function you are calling so it can get the values when the submit button is pressed.
Also you probably want to use an Or instead when validating the fields.  Here is an example:

```
function triggerCalc(){
        var user = document.forms[0].username.value;
        var pw = document.forms[0].password.value;

    if (pw.length < 5 || user.length < 3){
            alert("An error occured");
            }
```

If you're doing any kind of validation, there are some great jQuery libraries that make it look great and are easy to implement.  You might want to to a quick google search.